# Start service from system app in a custom rom

Tags: java, android, android-source, custom-rom

My usecase is really simple, I want to create a system app which starts a Service. (I'm new to custom-rom development)

To do so I've added: `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in my AndroidManifest.xml. As of now I'm still using an official Android version in my emulator (which is probably why I'm getting this issue)

I start my service with:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) context.startForegroundService(service);
else context.startService(service);
```

Unfortunately the service doesn't start and I get the following error:

```xml
Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: 
android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService:1466 
android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService:649
```

---

EDIT: When looking to the source file the warn comes from the [`startForegroundService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1393) which does:

```java
@Override
public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
    warnIfCallingFromSystemProcess();
    return startServiceAsUser(service, mUser);
}
```

---

EDIT2: After some more investigation, I think the issue comes from

```xml
type=1400 audit(0.0:31): avc: denied { create } for name="mgmtsocket" scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
```

---

EDIT3: More informations:

- I'm testing against a rooted emulator which runs on Android 8 API 26 (official version)
- I've signed my app using the AOSP key from [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_build/blob/master/target/product/security/) and using the following command line `apksigner sign --key platform.pk8 --cert platform.x509.pem filename.apk`
- Concerning my permissions and service I have:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: The warning is fine. You would need to share more details here, what android version it is? Did you sign the app with the platform key? Does it have all the pemissions?

Comment: I've added the info Rajat :)